# Difference between "greater than" and "subtract" in JavaScripts sort

Tags: javascript, sorting

I was using the sort algorithm like this

```
top.sort(function(a,b){ return b > a});
```

I expected the array be ordered descending. It worked for `top = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`
But  with `top = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]` I got an unexpected result like this

```
[6, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

I have discovered that Ive used the sort function wrong. I should have used

```
top.sort(function(a,b){ return b - a});
```

Now whats the difference? Why does the top one not work like I expected (but works with a array length smaller than 11?

Comment: When sorting, the values `1`,`0`, and `-1` each have different results. [See the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: Weird: http://jsfiddle.net/9Lw4r69f/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The sort function callback expects three possible return values:

> less than 0
>
> 0
>
> greater than 0

To tell it whether two values are the same or which is greater.  Your single comparison was only returning `true` or `false` which would be cast to `1` or `0` which is not enough information to correctly evaluate which one is greater.  It could work when `b` was greater than `a`, but would return `false` (likely interpreted as `0`) when `a` was greater than `b` which would wrongly tell the sort algorithm that these two values are equal.

On the other hand,

```
return b - a
```

correctly provides all three return values for all possible numeric values of `b` and `a` and thus it works properly.  If your values were not numbers, then you would have to more explicitly code a comparison that will return the three types of return values.  Returning the results of the subtraction just happens to meet the sort callback criteria.  It is certainly not the only way to code a comparison function.

In fact, if you want to sort an array of strings, you can use a different type of comparison that is also coded to return the three types of return values:

```js
    var result = ["hello", "goodbye", "adios"].sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.localeCompare(b);
    });

    document.write(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: It should be noted that `b - a` incidentally solves this issue.  However, if OP wasn't dealing with numbers and was instead dealing with objects/strings/etc, they would need to manually specify the cases for -1/0/1.

Comment: @Mr.Llama - More info added to that effect.  I'm going to add some more examples for other data types also.