# JavaScript Sort by number in a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

How could i sort e.g an array like this one:

```
[
  '<@520968882077433856> is level **7,64** _(18115.5 total xp)_',
  '<@289037609274048513> is level **7,07** _(14473 total xp)_',
  '<@672835870080106509> is level **8,25** _(22473.5 total xp)_',
  '<@536686935134175254> is level **6,22** _(10184.5 total xp)_',
]
```

I would like to sort it by the amount of total xp, so the number within  the brackets.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the sort callback. Extract the number with a regular expression:

```js
const data = [
  '<@520968882077433856> is level **7,64** _(18115.5 total xp)_',
  '<@289037609274048513> is level **7,07** _(14473 total xp)_',
  '<@672835870080106509> is level **8,25** _(22473.5 total xp)_',
  '<@536686935134175254> is level **6,22** _(10184.5 total xp)_',
];

const regex = /(?<=_\()[\d.]+/;
data.sort((a, b) => +a.match(regex) - +b.match(regex));
console.log(data);
```

The `+` is used to convert the returned array (with one match element) to a string and then that to a number. You could use `?.[0]` to actually *get* that first array element.

Comment: This could fail should some (unshown) entries happen to have more than one decimal number.

Comment: That could, but it requires that the decimal number follows the literal `_(`. Seems quite a strong condition already. And in that case the first gets precedence.

Answer (score 1):

We can try sorting using a custom lambda expression:

```js
var input = [
    '<@520968882077433856> is level **7,64** _(18115.5 total xp)_',
    '<@289037609274048513> is level **7,07** _(14473 total xp)_',
    '<@672835870080106509> is level **8,25** _(22473.5 total xp)_',
    '<@536686935134175254> is level **6,22** _(10184.5 total xp)_',
];
var output = input.sort( (a, b) => parseFloat(a.match(/(\d+(?:\.\d+)?) total xp\b/)[1]) - parseFloat(b.match(/(\d+(?:\.\d+)?) total xp\b/)[1]));
console.log(output);
```

In the above we are extracting the number which is followed by `total xp`, parsing it as a float, and then using that value in the sorting comparator.  If you want descending order, then just reverse the inequality in the lambda function.

Comment: On the use of `>` here: [Difference between "greater than" and "subtract" in JavaScripts sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32704651/difference-between-greater-than-and-subtract-in-javascripts-sort)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another try, looking for a space after the number:

```js
const arr=[
  '<@520968882077433856> is level **7,64** _(18115.5 total xp)_',
  '<@289037609274048513> is level **7,07** _(14473 total xp)_',
  '<@672835870080106509> is level **8,25** _(22473.5 total xp)_',
  '<@536686935134175254> is level **6,22** _(10184.5 total xp)_',
];

function getN(s){
 return s.match(/_\((.+?) /)[1];
}
arr.sort((a,b)=>getN(a)-getN(b))

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```js
const array = [
    "<@520968882077433856> is level **7,64** _(18115.5 total xp)_",
    "<@289037609274048513> is level **7,07** _(14473 total xp)_",
    "<@672835870080106509> is level **8,25** _(22473.5 total xp)_",
    "<@536686935134175254> is level **6,22** _(10184.5 total xp)_",
];

const extractDigitNumber = (string) => {
    return string.match(/(?<=\_\()(.*?)(?=\)\_)/)[0].replace(/[^\d\.]+/g, '') 
}

array.sort((a, b) => {
    return extractDigitNumber(a) - extractDigitNumber(b)
})

console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

***Details are commented in example***

```js
let data = [
  '<@520968882077433856> is level **7,64** _(18115.5 total xp)_',
  '<@289037609274048513> is level **7,07** _(14473 total xp)_',
  '<@672835870080106509> is level **8,25** _(22473.5 total xp)_',
  '<@536686935134175254> is level **6,22** _(10184.5 total xp)_',
]

/*
* - .map() through array 
* - on every iteration run .match() using this regex:
*   /(\d+\.?\d*)(?=\stotal)/ which means:
    "match one or more numbers, then a possible dot,
    and then possible numbers, but only if it's followed
    by a space and literal 'total'"
* - return a match in an array and the current index
* - .sort() the sub-arrays by their first index (sub[0])
*/
let indices = data.map((str, idx) => [+str.match(/(\d+\.?\d*)(?=\stotal)/g), idx]).sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0]);
console.log(JSON.stringify(indices));

//Define an empty array
let result = [];
/*
* - run new array of arrays with .forEach()
* - get the string within the original array (data) by
    the current sub-array's second index (sub[1])
* - push the value into the empty array (result)
*/
indices.forEach((sub, idx) => result.push(data[sub[1]]));
console.log(result);
```